# How to use fgets to read and count charaters

Tags: c

Let's say I want to count characters abcdef... from stdin.

Code:

```
int string[100] = "";
int a_count = 0...

while(fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin))
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 100; y ++)
    {
        if(string[y] == 'a') a_count++;
        if(string[y] == 'b') b_count++;
           ...and so on...
    }
    //here I reset the string to empty.
}
```

The code above work incorrectly (more count than it's supposed to), where did I make logical mistakes?

Comment: `int string[100];` should be `char string[100];`. And later in the loop use `sizeof(string)` instead of `100`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to terminate your `for` loop at the end of the actual string, rather than looping over the entire array.  You need to stop when you see a NUL terminator.

```
while (fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin) != NULL)
{
    for(int y = 0; string[y] != 0; y ++)
    {
        if(string[y] == 'a') a_count++;
        if(string[y] == 'b') b_count++;
           ...and so on...
    }
}
```

You do not need to set the string to 'empty' after processing it.  Later `fgets()` calls will just overwrite it, and that's fine.

Also, you might think of better ways to write the actual counters, but that's not the question you asked.

Comment: I terminated my for loop using the size of the char array(100) which is fixed.

Comment: This is wrong, `fgets()` returns the buffer you pass it, not the length of the string it read.

Comment: Right, but unless every line of input is 100 characters long, you will process leftover data that was in the buffer.  You didn't specify how you were 'resetting the string to empty', but if it didn't completely overwrite the entire buffer, then your `for` loop would see leftover data from previous `fgets()` calls.

Comment: @H2CO3: thinko.  You are correct.  Will fix it.  I don't know why I made that mistake, but I won't defend it.  It's fixed now.

Comment: @user1701840:  Both do the same thing.  Thanks to the 'usual integer promotions', the character `'\0'` and the integer `0` have the same value in the comparison.

Comment: @JoeZ That has nothing to do with promotions. Character literals are already of type `int`. It's just that the escape sequence `\0` is defined to have the numeric value zero.

Comment: @H2CO3:  Then why does `sizeof( '\0' )` return 1, but `sizeof( 0 )` returns 4?  (Try it!)

Comment: @H2CO3:  Interesting.  This seems to be a difference between C and C++, as when I tried it in C++ they return different values.  I didn't think they differed on this detail.

Comment: @JoeZ Oh, C++... You didn't say you were compiling this as C++! This is C code, and not C++, so it should be compiled with a C compiler. One cannot possibly compile C code with a C++ compiler correctly. And indeed, the type of character literals in C++ is `char` (to facilitate outputting characters *sensibly* when overloaded operators on streams need to choose from the possible overloads), but in C, the type of a character literal is `int` because most character-handling functions and macros work with `int`s (in order to be able to handle `EOF` which doesn't fit in a `char`, etc.)

Comment: @H2CO3:  Well, as I said, I didn't think they differed on this point, because the usual integer promotions would still promote a `char` to `int` in just about any circumstance that matters in C.  That's why the `string[i] != 0` test works just fine, right?  `string` isn't an array of `int`.

I guess this is more a case of where C++ cleaned up something that could have been done differently in C, without diminishing C's usefulness.  (ie. if `char` literals were actually `char`, they'd still work as you expect.)

Comment: Oh, and a screen shot comparing C and C++ on this point for the curious:  http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/images/sizeof_char_literal.png

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not only counting the characters in the string, but any garbage that's in the **entire buffer.** You don't want to do that. Loop until the end of the string only.

Furthermore, you can replace the enormous chained `if` with a simple table/array lookup, like this:

```
int counts[1 << CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };

while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
    const char *p = buf;
    while (*p != 0) {
        counts[*p++]++;
    }
}
```

Then, at the end, you can retrieve the count of a particular character as follows:

```
printf("'a': %d occurrences\n", counts['a']);
```

etc.

Comment: @JoeZ Unless there are non-printable characters (code >= 128 in ASCII, the sign bit set in general, assuming a 2's complement representation for signed integers) in the string, it will. But you can cast `*p++` to `unsigned char` at any time anyways.

Comment: By that argument, you should use `counts[1 << (CHAR_BIT - 1)]`.  ;-)

Comment: @JoeZ Well, not if I actually do the cast :P

Comment: I'm just saying that leaving it signed, on the assumption there are no negative values is inconsistent with declaring an array that holds the full `CHAR_BIT` range.  Either do the cast, or use an array half the size.